# Count the number of column values (number of unique values of column) that have at least one non null response

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what my dataframe looks like:

| Year | State | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2018 | 1 | 2 | Nan |
| 2018 | 1 | NaN | 1 |
| 2018 | 2 | NaN | 1 |
| 2018 | 2 | NaN | 2 |
| 2018 | 3 | 3 | NaN |
| 2019 | 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2019 | 1 | 3 | NaN |
| 2019 | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 2019 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2019 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 2019 | 2 | 3 | NaN |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2020 | 2 | NaN | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | NaN | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | NaN |
| 2020 | 4 | NaN | NaN |
| 2020 | 4 | 1 | NaN |

##### Desired Output

```
                            Year     2018     2019     2020
 Var1   Num of States w/ non-null     2        2        3
 Var2   Num of States w/ non-null     2        0        1
```

I want to count the number of unique values of the variable `State` that have at least one non null response for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you are looking for:

```
out = pd.concat([
    df.dropna(subset='Var1').pivot_table(columns='Year',
                                         values='State',
                                         aggfunc='nunique'),
    df.dropna(subset='Var2').pivot_table(columns='Year',
                                         values='State',
                                         aggfunc='nunique')
]).fillna(0).astype(int)
out.index = ['Var1 Num of States w/non-null', 'Var2 Num of states w/non-null']
```

print(out):

```
Year                           2018  2019  2020
Var1 Num of States w/non-null     2     2     3
Var2 Num of states w/non-null     2     0     1
```